# Add certain elements inside a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list with strings and I would like to add two elements sitting next to each other if they are not letters. Here is my list.

```
n=['u', '<', '=', 'd', 'd', '<', '<', 'f']
```

Now I would like to combine the greater than, equals and lower than signs inside the list to one string if they are next to each other. I have tried a bunch of methods and can't find one that isn't super inefficient or doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the methods you tried that are inefficient?

Comment: I meant that I could probably think of 1 by only pulling the letters using ascii code, joining the signs separately and then inserting them all to a list with like 3 for loops, but I havent tried it because that is definitely not the way to go. I tried with an enumerator loop, but that gives me the wrong answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to efficiently iterate over these groups, then accumulate the results in a new list, either joining and appending or extending the group.... So:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> n = ['u', '<', '=', 'd', 'd', '<', '<', 'f']
>>> new_n = []
>>> for is_letter, group in groupby(n, str.isalpha):
...     if not is_letter:
...         new_n.append(''.join(group))
...     else:
...         new_n.extend(group)
...
>>> new_n
['u', '<=', 'd', 'd', '<<', 'f']
```

And just to clarify what `itertools.groupby` does:

```
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k,g in groupby(n, str.isalpha)]
[(True, ['u']), (False, ['<', '=']), (True, ['d', 'd']), (False, ['<', '<']), (True, ['f'])]
```

The nice thing is this does a single pass on the list (giving you linear time complexity), and should be as efficient as you can hope in terms of the grouping, because `itertools` is implemented in C.

Comment: Thank you so so much, I would never in a million years have thought of that.